# ODBC error - SQL0104 - Token = was not vaild. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW - Crystal report error in windows 7 machine

Tags: sql, windows-7, crystal-reports, db2, odbc

Our client have been using several crystal reports for many years in the windows XP machines and I am responsible for supporting these reports. It was working perfectly fine. Recently we have upgraded to windows 7 machine and one of the crystal report stopped functioning wherheas other crystal reports works correctly in windows 7 machine. I am unable to identify the reason why one report stopped functioning. The crystal report is called through a java application.Below is the error message I get,

```
ODBC error:[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token = was not vaild. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS HASH.
```

Above is the error message. The SQL of the report is as below,

```
SELECT
    customermastertable."customerFirstname", customermastertable."customer1Firstname",
    celebrationmastertable."celebrationnumber", celebrationmastertable."storenumber", celebrationmastertable."customerssurname", celebrationmastertable."customerssurname2", celebrationmastertable."activestatus",
    prodstoretable."storename"
FROM
    ("proddatatable"."customermastertable" customermastertable INNER JOIN "proddatatable"."celebrationmastertable" celebrationmastertable ON
        customermastertable."customernumber" = celebrationmastertable."customernumber1")
     INNER JOIN "proddatatable"."prodstoretable" prodstoretable ON
        celebrationmastertable."storenumber" = prodstoretable."storenumber" 
WHERE
    customermastertable."customernumber" = celebrationmastertable."customernumber1" AND
    celebrationmastertable."storenumber1" = prodstoretable."storenumber" AND
    celebrationmastertable."celebrationnumber" = '?'.
```

The last `celebrationnumber` is a parameter passed in runtime.

By comparing the above error message and the sql query, could you please advise what could have caused this report to stop working in windows 7 alone. This same report is working fine in windows xp machine.

Comment: The `= '?'` at the end doesn't look right to me. If it's a parameter marker, it shouldn't be surrounded by single quotes like that. What is the data type of the celebrationnumber column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. This error was due to a missing DLL file kept inside the C:/Windows/System32 folder. I have copied the dll file from the XP system to Windows 7 system which is required for the ODBC and the crystal report started working fine. Thank you Fred Sobotka for helping me in this problem.